# Cancel the effect of the last CSS rule

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In the following screenshot, Material-UI increases the bottom padding from 16px to 24px using the rule

```css
.MuiCardContent-root:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 24px;
}
```

[image: Card Content Bottom Padding 24px]

I would like to change it back to 16px, the value set by the previous rule in the hierarchy. How can I do it using either the Material-UI API or plain CSS?

I tried the following but it simply changed the value to 0:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(function (theme) {
    return {
        // ...
        cardContent: {
            '&:last-child': {
                paddingBottom: 'inherit|initial|revert|unset', // (only one at a time, of course...)
            },
        },
    };
});

// ...
    <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
// ...
```

Of course I could hard-code it to 16px but I would rather avoid this option for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain on the specifics of the MaterialUI stuff you're using but you should be able to use `unset` to tell the `:last-child` to use whatever it gets via the cascade (i.e. inherit the standard value from `.MuiCardContent-root`)

Comment: I tried `unset`. It doesn't work this way. It resets `padding-bottom` to 0. Nor does `revert`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset.

Comment: @RonInbar Hmmm, have you tried `inherit`? That said I'm doubtful that will work either, your best be would be to remove the unwanted rule completely but that may be easier said than done.

Comment: I tried all the special values suggested by DevTools: `inherit | initial | revert | unset`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your criteria is that in this situation the last child should not be treated any differently because of it's `last-child` status, the best approach would be to add a new class to the HTML markup.

Then, qualify the CSS that only pick the last child that *doesn't* feature that class.

This will therefore not inadvertantly effect any other similar elements in other pages

```css
    .materialUI {
        padding-bottom:16px;
        color: #f00000;
    }
    .materialUI:not(.notThisOne):last-child {
         padding-bottom:24px;
         color: #330;
         font-weight:bold;
         font-size:1.5rem;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <div class='materialUI'>
            <p>Hello this is the page you want to edit</p>
        </div>
        <div class='materialUI notThisOne'>
            <p>Horse must not be last childed</p>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    ----------------------------------

    
    <div>
        <div class='materialUI'>
            <p>Any OtherPage</p>
        </div>
        <div class='materialUI'>
            <p>Other Page Last Child</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
```